# extract duplicate characters from a string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a homework assignment where I have to extract duplicate characters from a string and place them in another string.
exp:

```
const str = "love to learn javascript"
```

the new string would be

```
const str2 = "love tarnjscip"
```

I didn't made any try as I'm a beginner and I don't have an initial idea how to start (I think the solution is a nested loop)

Can you help me and give me different ways to handle this kind of exercise?

Comment: **Don't look the answers below**, do it yourself. Go through characters, count occurrences of every character (e.g., character `"a"` occurs in the string 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 times; same for each character), then return only those characters that occur 2+ times.

Comment: Also, StackOverflow is best suited for solving concrete software problems – like, "I can't start the process", or "why do I see this unexpected result?", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an object to easily keep track of which letters you already encountered.

```js
const str = "love to learn javascript"

let str2 = "";

let letters = {};

for(let i=0, l=str.length; i<l; ++i) {
  let letter = str[i];
  if(!letters[letter]) { // if the object does not have a property
                         // named after the current letter yet
    str2 += letter; // then add that letter to the result string
  }
  letters[letter] = 1; // set the object property for the current letter
}

console.log(str2)
```

Comment: I know OP's str2 match your result, but he says `extract duplicate characters` but then i don't think it should return `njscip` because they only exist once

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen with the given example, I was reading it as "only keep the first occurrence of each character in the result", as the only thing that could make much sense. But you are right of course, the description and the given example do not really match.

Comment: @CBroe indeed I didn't understand this statement `!letters[letter]` thus the related comment **if the object does not have a property named after the current letter yet**
what does it did exactly ? is it equivalent to `!letters.letter`
on the other hand what is the purpose of `letters[letter] = 1;`

Comment: No, `letters.letter` and `letters[letter]` are not the same thing - the first one accesses a property that is _literally_ named `letter`, whereas the second one addresses a property named after whatever _value_ `letter` currently contains. `!letters[letter]` will be true, if no property with the name of the value currently contained in `letter` exists on the object. `letters[letter] = 1;` assigns a value to that property, so from there on, it will exist.

Comment: ok, on my part I'd rather work on str2, check if it `includes(str[i])` then make addition assignment :p

Comment: @CBroe what if I wanteted to concatenate **,** after every iteration i.e do so `str2 += str[i] +', ';` hence the output would be `"l, o, v, e, t, a, r, n, j, s, c, i, p, "` but Idon't want to print **,** after last index

Comment: Then you can put the letters into an array first, instead of appending them to a string - and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array elements into a string value afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe I've made it this way `if(i < str.length-1){
     str2 += letter + ' ,'; 
    }
    else{
     str2 += letter; 
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Set` to get your desired result provided:

```js
const r = [...new Set("love to learn javascript")].join('');
console.log(r);
```

Regarding the "extracting duplicate values" phrase, `Set` could be useful too:

```js
// if char is registered and not a space, 
// add it to duplicates if not added yet otherwise register it

const dups = new Set, set = new Set;
[..."love to learn javascript"].forEach(char =>
  set.has(char) && char !== ' ' && !dups.has(char) && dups.add(char) || set.add(char)
);

console.log('duplicated chars:', ...[...dups].sort());
```

Comment: OP writes: `I have to extract duplicate characters from a string and place them in another string` your result is showing some characters that has only been used once.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen OPs often aren't clear enough. the desired result is provided - the new string would be

const str2 = "love tarnjscip", i provided the same the result, what's the problem?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen fixed, added as a second part of my answer, you could remove your upvote please, thanks

Answer (score 0):

here i created an empty array and i pushed to it every unique letter, then in the next round i check if a letter already added so it means the letter repeated then i call continue to skip to the next round if the letter repeated or i add the letter if it is not.
hope this works for you.

```js
const sentence = "love to learn javascript"

const letters = []
let result = ''
for(const item of sentence)
{
  const check = letters.find((i)=>i===item)
  if(check)continue;
  letters.push(item)
  result += item
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code iterates through each character in the str string. It checks if the current character is a duplicate by comparing the last occurrence index with the first occurrence index of that character. If they are not equal, it means the character appears more than once.

```
const str = "love to learn javascript";
let str2 = "";

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str.lastIndexOf(str[i]) !== str.indexOf(str[i])) {
    if (!str2.includes(str[i])) {
      str2 += str[i];
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo**

```js
const str = "love to learn javascript";
let str2 = "";

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str.lastIndexOf(str[i]) !== str.indexOf(str[i])) {
    if (!str2.includes(str[i])) {
      str2 += str[i];
    }
  }
}

console.log(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from the documentation of Javascript MDN.

[Set -Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Set objects are collections of values.

A value in the set may only occur once. it is unique in the set's collection.
It is, on average, faster than the `Array.prototype.includes`

Therefore, for finding duplicate characters comes very handy.

```js
let str = 'love to learn javascript';
const remDup= [...new Set(str)].sort().join("");


console.log(remDup);
```